# SharePoint CSOM: ClientContext holds Dictionary ObjectPathIdentity-Objects

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I use CSOM to import some Documents to Sharepoint.
When I execute my Importer I have seen, that it uses more and more Memory. The Analysis have shown, that the ClientContext owns holds DIctionary with all ObjectPathIdentity-Objets.
This gives me a Memory-Problem when I export a lot of documents to different Folders in Sharepoint.

Is there a solution to clear this dictionary or to disable this caching-mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

I solve the same problem, try this, maybe help you

clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;

clientContext.DisableReturnValueCache = true;

.......execute query......

clientContext.Dispose();

clientContext = null;

Comment: Could you add documentation reference too?